# Yes/No loop using joptionpane in java not looping properly

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

After the user plays a game they get asked wather they want to play again if they selected yes then the game its played and then they are asked again and again until they selected no. When i run the program the dialog box doesnt appear but when i remove s.playGame(); it runs fine.
Code for playgame https://www.pastiebin.com/58f937756037a

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

do {
    s.playGame();
    numberOfGoes++;
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?", "HINT", dialogButton);

    if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

} while (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a read through [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) which has a number of examples which demonstrate how to solev your issue

Comment: i will be sure to look into it thanks

Comment: "_when i remove s.playGame(); it runs fine_" It's there, it's broken. It's gone, it works. My guess is that's where the problem is. You didn't think it would be a good idea to show us that code you removed?

Comment: ive added the code now.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). And add it here, not at an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"choose one", "choose one", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (result== JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Here is minimal testable exmaple for you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?", "HINT", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("No chosen");
    }

    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Picked YES");
    }
}
```

Adapt it to suit your needs

Comment: int result=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?", "HINT");     
"no suitable method found for showConfirmDialog(<null>,String,String)"
getting this error.

Comment: Pick suitable one. Edited for you. You should get the point. Here you have api details and explanation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: https://www.pastiebin.com/58f93bffb22e2 this is what i have now still no joptionpane.

Comment: @Frank1801 edited with minimal working example. Rest is up to you.